# Downloading Script Dependencies in Parallel RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Following [this RequireJS example](http://requirejs.org/docs/1.0/docs/faq-optimization.html#priority) I'm trying to have a single file for all vendor js assets like jquery and foundation, whilst loading page specific code in other modules.

While I can build and copy the js successfully (using grunt requirejs optimiser) into a `build` folder, the baseUrl in the `require.config` is obviously now wrong.

`baseUrl: 'js'` points to `public/js` instead of `public/build/js` and so all paths are incorrect.

Is there a way of dynamically updating the `baseUrl` when running the optimiser? So it points to `public/build/js`?

**Here's my grunt task:**

```
requirejs: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            baseUrl: '<%=pkg.paths.js%>',
            dir:'project/public/build/js',
            mainConfigFile: '<%=pkg.paths.js%>main.js',
            optimize: 'none',
            removeCombined: true,
            uglify2: {
                no_mangle: true,
                compress: {
                    drop_console: true
                }
            },
            modules: [
                {
                    name: 'vendorCommon'
                },
                {
                    name: 'dashboard',
                    exclude: ['vendorCommon']
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Vendor Common**

```
define(['jquery', 'foundation'],
function () {
    //Just an empty function, this is a place holder
    //module that will be optimized to include the
    //common depenendencies listed in this module's dependency array.
});
```

**Require Config**

```
require.config({

    baseUrl: '/js',

    priority: ['vendorCommon'],

    paths: {
        'vendorCommon':'vendor/vendor-common',
        'jquery':'../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min',
        'foundation':'../bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation',
        'dashboard':'views/dashboard'
    },

    shim: {
        'foundation': ['jquery']
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the optimizer's [`onBuildWrite`](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/5e5c392c2d3814ecd76f536bc740df78ad83aa22/build/example.build.js#L542) setting to modify some modules when they are optimized. If your configuration is included in your optimized bundle then you could use `onBuildWrite` to patch it:

```
onBuildWrite: function (moduleName, path, contents) {
    if (moduleName === '<%=pkg.paths.js%>main') {
        return contents.replace("baseUrl: '/js'", "baseUrl: '/build/js'");
    }
    return contents;
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm writing this off the top of my head. Beware of typos.

Another possibility would be to override `baseUrl` at runtime. RequireJS is able to combine multiple configurations into a single configuration. A new value of `baseUrl` in a later call would override the earlier value. So if you have a way to set up the optimized version of your app (for instance, through different HTML served by your server) to call `require.config({baseUrl: '/build/js'});` *after* the call you show in your question but *before* any code that needs the correct `baseUrl`, this could also be an option.

Comment: I thought about creating a separate config for production but for me, your onBuildWrite is a much better solution. Thanks!